# Make column value as a row

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine

I'm not sure I titled the question correctly, I'll try to explain what I mean by example.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  d.name_ascii,
  d.price,
  t.whois_price
FROM domain d
  JOIN tld t ON d.tld_id = t.id
  JOIN user_tld ut ON t.id = ut.tld_id
WHERE ut.user_id = 1
  AND d.name_ascii IN ('domain.com')
```

which returns the following:

```
+------------+---------+-------------+
| name_ascii |  price  | whois_price |
+------------+---------+-------------+
| domain.com | 321.000 | 15.000      |
+------------+---------+-------------+
```

It's ok, but I need next result:

```
+------------------+---------+
|       item       |  price  |
+------------------+---------+
| domain.com       | 321.000 |
| domain.com whois | 15.000  |
+------------------+---------+
```

That is I need to *remove* 3-rd column named `whois_price` and *insert* it as another row with the same `price` value and *concatenated* `name_ascii` value with "whois" as `item` column.

I have no idea how to solve it. Any advice, hint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be with a UNION.

```
SELECT
  d.name_ascii as item,
  d.price
FROM domain d
WHERE d.name_ascii IN ('domain.com')
UNION ALL
SELECT
  concat(d.name_ascii,' whois'),
  t.whois_price
FROM domain d
  JOIN tld t ON d.tld_id = t.id
  JOIN user_tld ut ON t.id = ut.tld_id
WHERE ut.user_id = 1
  AND d.name_ascii IN ('domain.com')
```

The first part gets price, the second part gets the whois price.
Here's a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5164/3